# Java: count the total number of items in a HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, collections

I have this `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>` , is there a way to count the total number of items in all the Lists in the Map without going through all Lists?

Or should I iterate through the Map and along all lists ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to see [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and use [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) instead of that. The Multimap.size() method will give the answer you want.

Comment: The program will still iterate through all elements (just in case the author asked his question out of performance reasons and not just laziness to code).

Comment: no... see the source code (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMultimap.java) line 164-167

Answer (score 30):

As of Java 8 you accomplish that with an one-liner:

```
Integer sum = map.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```

Comment: Beware of the `Non-static method 'size' cannot be referenced from a static context` error

Answer (score 16):

Use the size() method defined for HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> hMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>();
int hSize;
/*
    put/remove operations

*/

hSize = hMap.size(); // Gives the total no. of elements of HashMap
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#size--) this is not correct. `HashMap.size()` "Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map."

Comment: This will only count the number of key-value pairs as @linqu mentioned. So using `hMap.size ()` for the following key-values: `["key1", [Item1, Item2]], ["key2", [Item3, Item4]]` would only return 2, instead we want 4 since there are 4 `Item` objects

Comment: @Navigatron huh? then you would just multiply `map.size()*2`, I don't understand.

Comment: @AlexanderMills If it was just a map with the value was *not* a list, you could multiply it by 2. But since the value is an arraylist, there could be any number of objects in that list. You need to count the amount of objects in each list, per key of the map. Using `map.size()*2` will not work for the example: `["key1", [Item1, Item2]], ["key2", [Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6]]`, since the total number of values is 6.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to iterate over the `List<Item>` values in your `Map` and count the total. The `Map` doesn't have any knowledge of what values you're putting into it, so it can't provide a facility to get you a total. The code you need is fairly simple:

```
int total = 0;
for (List<Item> list : map.values()) {
    total += list.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Map` itself has no a priori knowledge about the values stored in it, except that they are `Object`s (thus can't be expected to perform any operations on them, other than calling `toString()`, `equals()` and/or `hashCode()`), there is no other way than iterating through its elements and calculating the sum manually.

Answer (score 2):

Multimap sounds like the right choice however, you could do

```
public static <K, V> int count(Map<K, ? extends Collection<V>> map) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Collection<V> coll : map.values()) count += coll.size();
    return count;
}
```

BTW: You may want count to return a long ;)

Comment: Why ? no one is going to put that many items (2Billion+) into a map

Comment: Never say never. Using a long would mean you never need worry about it. ;)

Answer (score -1):

If Any one still looking out for answers

Here is the code posted

```
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<ShortListedFlats>>> iter = rentShortListedFlats
            .entrySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        ArrayList<ShortListedFlats> shortLists = iter.next().getValue();

        counter = counter + shortLists.size();

    }
```

Comment: Answers were already given years ago. Furthermore a foreach loop is way better to read than this manual `Iterator` approach

Comment: I don't see any iterator answers given secondly i calculated the time

Comment: Iterators are faster than for each loops for simple reason that they work on entries which hash maps are made of so please think twice before downvoting an answer

Comment: A *foreach* loop *uses* a iterator: `for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<ShortListedFlats>> entry : rentShortListedFlats.entrySet())` is equivalent but better readable than your code. @Peter Lawrey provided a superiour answer to yours.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need a for loop:

```
public static int countItems(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> yourMap){
    int counter = 0;
    for(ArrayList<Item>> list: yourMap.values()){
        counter += list.size();
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: ArrayList has size() so the second loop is unnecessary

Comment: -1 - this solution contains a number of errors.  For a start, `HashMap` does not implement `Iterable` so the outer `for` loop is a compilation error.

Comment: First thanks for the critics. I just wrote that before I had to change the room and actually didn't test it. Will edit it of course.

Comment: more suggestion erikb: You don't need the cast because that's what generic is for. And moreover there is values() method in map