# How to increment count in java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Map` and `List` which looks like

```
int total = 0;
int incr = 10;
Map<String, Boolean> hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put("A", true);
hashMap.put("B", false);
hashMap.put("C", true);

List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
states.add("A");
states.add("B");
states.add("D");
states.add("E");
states.add("F");
```

Everytime I find a key from the list in the `Map` then I want to increment my total by increment value;

```
states.stream()
            .filter(s -> hashMap.containsKey(s) && hashMap.get(s))
            .forEach((s) -> {total = total + incr;} );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: count the total number of items in a HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496944/java-count-the-total-number-of-items-in-a-hashmapstring-arrayliststring)

Comment: btw: To avoid two look ups calling `hashMap.containsKey(s) && hashMap.get(s)` you could use an `Optional` instead: `Optional.ofNullable(hashMap.get(s)).orElse(false)`

Comment: @LuCio or just `hashMap.getOrDefault(s, false)`

Comment: @Holger Of course ... that is even shorter and more readable.

Comment: **Warning** : `new HashMap()` – you are using a raw type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable `total` must be final (that is: carry the keyword final) or be effectively final (that is: you only assign a value to it once outside of the lambda). Otherwise, you can't use that variable within your lambda expression. You may fix it like this,

```
int total = states.stream()
    .filter(s -> hashMap.containsKey(s) && hashMap.get(s))
    .mapToInt(k -> incr).sum();
```

As mentioned in the below comment, this can be further simplified as,

```
int total = states.stream()
    .filter(s -> hashMap.getOrDefault(s, false))
    .mapToInt(k -> incr).sum();
```

Comment: You don’t need to perform two map lookup. Just use `.filter(s->hashMap.getOrDefault(s, false))`. An alternative to `… .mapToInt(k -> incr).sum()` is `(int)( … .count() * incr)`…